# Function inside a template is called many times (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-template

Today I had to fix a performance issue caused by this code: **Pay attention to updateStats called inside the template**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="entityGrouper">

<section>

<div>
<ul ng-click="hideEntityBox = !hideEntityBox">
<li>
{{ entityNode.name }}
</li>
<li ng-repeat="breadcrumbItem in entityNode.breadcrumb">
{{ breadcrumbItem }}
</li>
</ul>
{{ updateStats(entityNode) }}
<span ng-include="'/mypath/views/resume.html'"></span>
</div>

<div>

<div ng-repeat="entityNode in entityNode.group" ng-include="'entityGrouper'"></div>
<div ng-repeat="entity in entityNode.group" ng-include="'entityBox'"></div>

</section>

</script>
```

Template use:

```
<div ng-repeat="entityNode in entityNode.group" ng-include="'entityGrouper'"></div>
```

After debugging this code I discovered that this function was called many more time than the array size (my array has 4 objects and the function was called more than 100 times), even mouse hover called this function. **I fixed that by just putting a ng-init inside the template and now it's working properly, but I didn't figure out why this function has been called so many times. Is there something about two way data binding?**

Comment: Are you recursively calling the same template? there is again a `<div ng-repeat="entityNode in entityNode.group" ng-include="'entityGrouper'"></div>` call made inside the template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening not because of two-way data binding (it is applicable to form inputs), but rather because of angular change detection. Angular periodically checks if any of the values, bound to a template, changed, and if so - updates its value in the view. Typically, it is triggered by user generated events. In order to check if the value of `updateStats(entityNode)` changed, Angular evaluates it, which causes the performance hit.

To fix this, you may use previously mentioned one-time binding `updateStats(entityNode)` **if the result is set once and will never change in the future**. I guess, this is your case, and you have already moved the evaluation to `ng-init`. For values that update with time, it would be better to create a separate property in `entityNode` like `entityNode.stats`, display it in the template and run the `updateStats(entityNode)` in your controller or service only when necessary. By doing that, you will prevent running `updateStats(entityNode)` on each digest cycle (you have already seen how often that is) and thereby improve your app's performance.

Answer (score 7):

It is usually recommended to use a `$watch` for scenarios like this. Since you are binding a function `{{updateStats()}}`, it will execute on every digest cycle.

So in your code whenever a digest cycle is called, it will also call the function. And digest cycles are frequently called internally in Angular.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is the result of a digest cycle.

Adding a `::` will call the function once / one-time binding.

`{{ ::updateStats(entityNode) }}`

Comment: what :: exactly do?

Comment: `::` offers one time binding. If you prefix an expression with this, it will stop running or recalculating after the first digest. More information *One-time binding* section of the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: gives me a syntax error?